# Can OpenGeo Community Edition be used in commercial project?

Tags: boundless-suite, license, free-software

I would like to know if the [Community edition](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/community/) of OpenGeo Suite can be used in a commercial project?

And, if so, what are the conditions of use for the Community edition?

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  At its [**home page**](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/community/) it says that "the OpenGeo Suite Community Edition is licensed under the [**GNU General Public License (GPL)**](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)" so this should really be a question about what you can do with that license.  This is therefore not a GIS specific question.

Comment: The Community Edition no longer exists and the link to its home page is broken.

Answer (score 13):

*Update*: Boundless no longer has a Community Edition of the OpenGeo Suite. It simply offers a download at : http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/download/. They now have an Enterprise Edition which provides support and other features/tools (e.g Composer)

According to their [twitter account](https://twitter.com/boundlessgeo/status/388674817634746368):

> You can do anything [*with the download*] you could have previously
>   done with Community Edition. We've collapsed the distinctions.

The original Answer is as follows:

---

You can definitely use the Community Edition in a commercial project. The community edition has everything you would need. The things it is missing are support, bugfixes, and raster support.

You can get more information about the various editions here: http://opengeo.org/products/suite/buy/

The OpenGeo suite is Free OpenSource Software ([license under](http://opengeo.org/products/suite/community/) the GPL), and one of the main freedoms is to use the software for any purpose. The GPL allows the commercial usage of such software.